# Android push with new Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to integrate the Google Cloud Messaging in my application.
When i wan't register the mobile to the server, ih have this error :

```
    12-10 14:43:36.451: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22455): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
12-10 14:43:36.481: I/Appehour:GCM(22455): Registration not found.
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455): Process: com.appehour.jdm, PID: 22455
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:478)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:467)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.d(Unknown Source)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.b(Unknown Source)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at com.appehour.jdm.TestPush$registerInBackground.doInBackground(TestPush.java:170)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at com.appehour.jdm.TestPush$registerInBackground.doInBackground(TestPush.java:1)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-10 14:43:36.501: E/AndroidRuntime(22455):    ... 4 more
```

This is my AndroidManifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myApp"
    android:versionCode="13"
    android:versionName="1.3.9" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!-- Permissions pour le push -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <permission android:name="com.myApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.myApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        >

        <activity
            android:name="com.myApp.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" > 
        </activity>


         <activity 
              android:name="TestPush" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 

         </activity>


        <!-- Receiver pour le push -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.myApp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />


    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />         

    </application>
</manifest>
```

And my activity :

```
   package com.appehour.jdm;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class TestPush extends Activity{


public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
private static final String PREFS_GCM = "prefs_gcm";
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

/**
 * Substitute you own sender ID here. This is the project number you got
 * from the API Console, as described in "Getting Started."
 */
String SENDER_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

/**
 * Tag used on log messages.
 */
static final String TAG_LOGS = "Appehour:GCM";

TextView mDisplay;
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
SharedPreferences prefs;
Context context;

String regid;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.test_push);
    mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTestPush);


    // Check device for Play Services APK.
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);

        regid = getRegistrationId(context);

        if (regid.isEmpty()) {
           new registerInBackground().execute();
        }

    } else {
        Log.i(TAG_LOGS, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
    }



}

// You need to do the Play Services APK check here too.
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   // checkPlayServices();
}

 /* Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
 * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
 * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
 */
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i("Appehour identification Push", "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

/**
 * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
 * <p>
 * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
 *
 * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
 *         registration ID.
 */
private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG_LOGS, "Registration not found.");
        return "";
    }
    // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
    // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
    // app version.
    int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG_LOGS, "App version changed.");
        return "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}

/**
 * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
 */
private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
    // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
    // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
    return getSharedPreferences(PREFS_GCM,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

/**
 * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
 */
private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return packageInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // should never happen
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
    }
}


 private class registerInBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

     }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        String msg = "";
        try {
            if (gcm == null) {
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
            }

            regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
            msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
            Log.d(TAG_LOGS, "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid);

            // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
            // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
            // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
            // is using accounts.
            sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

            // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
            // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
            // message using the 'from' address in the message.

            // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
            storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            Log.e(TAG_LOGS, "Error :" + ex.getMessage());
            // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
            // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
            // exponential back-off.
        }
        return msg;
    }
 }


private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {

}

private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    Log.i(TAG_LOGS, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
    editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

I don't understand the problem.
Thank's if you know the issue.

Comment: How are you testing your code? on a real device? It requires devices running Android 2.2 or higher that also have the Google Play Store application installed, or or an emulator running Android 2.2 with Google APIs. However, you are not limited to deploying your Android applications through Google Play Store. (Ref.: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html)